# What kind of mechanisms are there to give an object free rotation?

Tags: mechanisms, bearings

I am doing a project where there is a plate with a hole on it where one ring will be mounted. The ring and plate need to be attached somehow. However, the ring must be able to rotate around the roll axis. I already have some ideas, but there are too complicated. (with bearing, etc) My questions is: what are some similar mechanisms that I can inspire? (The picture shown below is the basic demonstration of the project. The ring which is needed to be able to rotate is shown with the red color)

[image]

Comment: Show a picture of what you want to achieve, then we may be able to help.

Comment: What is so complicated about using an off the shelf bearing or bushing?

Answer (score 2):

Commercial display stands may give you an inspiration. You can simplify the idea for your project.

For example: https://tr.aliexpress.com/item/32915896443.html

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Make the external surface of the red ring have a bearing track and the matching track on the interior of the black plate so you have a roller bearing created by the two items.

Or have the track on the red ring with 4 or even 8 holes drilled into the plate which have screws with a roller at the tip.

[image: an idea:]

Comment: But in this case, the ring will not rotate I guess. Or am I missing something?

Comment: @mr21 key word roller : "with 4 or even 8 holes drilled into the plate which have screws with a roller at the tip" or even a ball bearing both spring loaded. It was an image to give you the idea, not a working drawing....