# How can I model two attached rotating rings?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, design, machining

I am trying to model an object in which there are two rings who are attached to each other and can rotate independently along the Y axis (see attached image).

The object needs to be machined and not too costly to produce, and solid (the rings won't detach if pulled onto).

I have little knowledge in mechanical engineering but I'm working with an engineer and I want to give them the right pointers.

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What kind of mechanisms are there to give an object free rotation?](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/29423/what-kind-of-mechanisms-are-there-to-give-an-object-free-rotation)

Comment: @SolarMike these might not work, the rings are thin and I want to have it machined

Comment: Then you may need to consider the shapes so that the bearing tracks also "clamp" the two parts together.

Comment: The answer linked doesn't give much to go from... what's the name of this type of joint, how does one make this type of joint with hard materials, etc

Comment: If you read my answer then the words "roller bearing" are there, many many different types - if you start searching you might find something that could work for you.

Comment: The object seen [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vMOsBG2JaZY) at 1:02 has no ball bearings and also has thin walls while being sturdy. Still unsure how to find what I'm looking for from the information on this page?

Comment: https://www.photo.net/discuss/threads/ball-bearing-lost.496229/